# General revealjs / impressjs question in quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto, reveal.js, impress.js

I wanted to get some advice on implementing the following but in R's quarto using css/scss. My background is not in `js`, `css` or `scss` but I have managed to download and install the `impress.js` files and get it working locally. It doesn't seem difficult to modify / edit for a standalone presentation but I was hoping to try and find a way to introduce data, interactively etc. into such a presentation.

Here is a link to the `ìmpressjs` demo:

https://impress.js.org/#/bored

Heres the github

https://github.com/impress/impress.js

Would it be possible to copy over the css/js files and use it in a quarto environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of a Quarto file that works with `impress.js`. Make sure that your `.qmd` file is in a folder with the "js" and "css" `impress.js` source files.

This example makes use of the [pandoc extension](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/8.18-divs-and-spans.html) `fenced_divs`, which is used by default in Quarto. It allows to define HTML `<div>`s by inserting fenced `:::` blocks.

````
---
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{=html}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/impress-common.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/impress-demo.css">
```

::: {#impress}

::: {#myFirstSlide .step .slide}

# My first slide

```{r}
plot(mtcars)
```


:::

::: {#my2ndSlide .step data-x="1000" data-y="1000" data-z="-1000" data-scale="2" data-rotate-z="90"}

# Powerful, but simple blah

:::

:::

```{=html}
<script src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script>impress().init()</script>
```
````

[image]

**EDIT:** I created an impress.js Quarto format extension: [Github](https://github.com/tilltnet/impressjs).

Comment: Thats amazing, thank you very much! Can you give me some more examples of how I can create more slides using different features of the impressjs example?

Comment: These two types are the main ones used in the demo. You can play with the `data-*:` values in the 2nd slide to see how it changes the behavior. Otherwise, study the source code of the impress.js demo for more inspiration. Look for the attributes in the `<div>`s with "step" class.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the `visualise your big thoghts` - I can't seem to figure out how to reference the `span class = "thoughts"` part.

The code from the `impress.js` presentation is `<div id="big" class="step" data-x="3500" data-y="2100" data-rotate="180" data-scale="6">
        <p>visualize your <b>big</b> <span class="thoughts">thoughts</span></p>
    </div>`

I currently have this:

`::: {#slide6 .step data-x="3500" data-y="2100" data-rotate="180" data-scale="6"}
Visualise your <span class="thoughts">big</span> thoguhts
:::`

Comment: instead of `#slide6` use `#big`

Comment: I created a [impress.js Quarto format extension](https://github.com/tilltnet/impressjs).

Comment: oh thats actually really great! I will ask any questions I have on the github page, thanks! I actually got a replica version working based on your suggestions but I had some issues integrating markdown styles into it. I will check out your version now :)